# Prove that $e^n$ converges to $0$ weakly (Brézis exercise 3.18)

Tags: functional-analysis

> For every integer n ≥ 1 let $e^n = (\underbrace{0, 0,..., 1}_{n}, 0, . . . ).$ Prove
> that $e^n→0$ as $n$ approaches infinity in $l^p$ weakly $σ(l^p,l^p{'})$ with $1 < p ≤ ∞$.

I've been stuck on this question for a while now.
So to prove weak convergence we need to show that $<f,e^n>$ goes to $0$, right?
In our case $<f,e^n>$ is just equal to $f_n$ because $e^n$ is $0$ everywhere except at the nth position.

Every answer to this question I've found so far just states that $f_n$ goes to $0$ and then concludes. But why does $f_n$ go to $0$? $f$ is in $l^p{'}$, so it's bounded, that I understand. But why does it go to $0$?

Comment: Convergent series have terms which go to zero.

Comment: Let $f$ be in $\ell^{p'}$ and $f_n$ the $n$-th component, then $(e^n, f) =f_n\xrightarrow{n\to \infty}0$ because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n^{p'}<\infty$

Answer (score 0):

If $p<\infty$ then

$(\ell^p)^\prime=\ell^q$ where $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$. Hence $(f_n)$ is $q$-summable thus a zero sequence.

Comment: $(f_n^q)$ is summable.